# Rails - Faye pushing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, faye

I dont know how to publish some data from rails server, I would like to do similar like in js

```
var publication = client.publish('channel', {data});
```

I found someting like that:

```
engine.publish(message, channels)
```

but dont know how to use it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

```
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
faye_server.get_client.publish('/foo', data )
```

Answer (score 1):

At server side, in js.erb file you will have to broadcast message to a channel. ie

```
<% broadcast "/messages/new" do %>
  $("#chat").append("<%= escape_javascript render(@message) %>");
<% end %>
```

To broadcast the message/data from controllers. ie

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do 
      broadcast "channel" do 
         @message.to_json
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

At client side you will have to include the faye javascript in layout or template and will have to subscribe the channel. ie

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "http://localhost:9292/faye.js" %>
```

and a dom container in layout or template. ie

```
<ul id="chat">
  <%= render @messages %>
</ul>
```

and Subscribe the channel via javascript. ie

```
$(function() {
  var faye = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
    faye.subscribe("/messages/new", function(data) {
    eval(data);
  });
});
```

reference - http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Comment: I don't want to display any data. My goal is only push it to client.

Comment: In that case you can do `broadcast` message at server side in any js.erb file or in controller action.

Comment: Yes I would like to do it within rails app. Could you give me example such broadcast in rails?

Comment: `<% broadcast "Channel" do %>`
   `<%= @message.to_josn %>`
`<% end %>`

Comment: I want to do nothing in view. I need controller method which will push data to client in real time after handshake

Comment: Client is on the other server. I deal with backend only

Comment: updated answer for broadcast from controller action.

Comment: I will check out it later and speak up